# Can't access GitHub through firewall even with Proxy setup: Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT

Tags: git, github, proxy

Trying to access Github through firewall fails with following message:

`$ git fetch origin master
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myrepo/myproject.git/': Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT`

Went through all possible proxy settings. I have set the following:


`http.proxy  to http://user:pwd@proxy:port

https.proxy to https://user:pwd@proxy:port

git config --global http.sslVerify false`

But nothing worked, still getting the same message. I have cntlm running (not sure if that is an issue).

I am using Git Bash on Windows 7.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by re-installing Git Bash again. I had to do that because I noticed I can access GitHub from Git Windows command line which means the issue is with Git Bash.